# Scraping a list separated by <br>-tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape a web site that has a list which uses a very unfortunate format:

```
<div class="post">
    <b>FIELD1</b><br/>FIELD2<br/>FIELD3<br/><br/>
    <b>FIELD1</b><br/>FIELD2<br/>FIELD3<br/><br/>
    <b>FIELD1</b><br/>FIELD2<br/>FIELD3<br/><br/>
</div>
```

I.e., everything is separated by `<br/>`-tags. A new element can be identified by a double `<br/>`-tag at the end of an element, and the new element begins with a `<br/>` tag. Making things worse, FIELD3 may also contain `<br/>` tags. Put differently, FIELD2 is "the field that comes after the closing `</b>` tag" and FIELD3 is "the field that comes before the double `<br/>` tag.

This is what I have so far:

Since I couldn't find a good way to grab FIELD2 and FIELD3, I tried creating a `<p>` tag around FIELD2 and 3 by replacing `</b><br/>` with `</b><p>` and `<br/><br/>` with `<br/><p>`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = response.xpath('//div[@id="mainDiv"]/div[1]')
    items = str.replace(items, "</b><br/>", "</b><p>")
    items = str.replace(items, "<br/><br/>", "</p><br/>")

    for item in items :
        dateX = item.xpath('.//b/text()').extract()
        infoX = item.xpath('.//p/text()').extract()
```

However, that doesn't work (`TypeError: descriptor 'replace' requires a 'str' object but received a 'SelectorList'`). That aside, I'm sure there has to be a better solution, but I can't seem to find what it is.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not split the string without using xpath?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: get the `innerHTML` of your initial `div` which gives you a string, split the string by `<br/>` which will give you ['<b>Field1</b>', 'Field2', ''Field3', '']`.

Comment: `'<b>FIELD1</b><br/>FIELD2<br/>FIELD3<br/><br/>'.split('<br/>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    items = response.xpath('//div[@id="mainDiv"]/div[1]')
    for item in items :

    i=1
    while (i < 10):
        field1 = item.xpath('.//b['+str(i)+']/text()').extract()    
        field2 = item.xpath('.//b['+str(i)+']/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()      
        field3 = item.xpath('.//b['+str(i)+']/following-sibling::text()[2]').extract()

        yield {
            'field1': field1
            ,'field2': field2
            ,'field3': field3
        }

        i=i+1
```

Only thing left now is to replace i < 10 with the correct total number, but that should be easy enough.

Thanks again, @Tomalak, for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

What about this (or something close to it):

```
def parse(self, response):
    posts = response.xpath('//div[@id="mainDiv"]/div[@class="post"]')
    for post in posts:
        field1 = post.xpath('./b/text()').extract()
        field2 = post.xpath('./br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()
        field3 = post.xpath('./br[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract()
```

Key point is: Don't use string functions (split, regex, search and replace) on HTML. This is a rule that always applies, but doubly so when you already have a fully parsed DOM tree with XPath support. There is an XPath expression for any node in the tree.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, thanks for your answer. I was thinking something along those lines. The problem is though that there is just one div surrounding ALL the rows. I think what you have would work if there was a div around EACH of the rows.

Comment: Well, the indexes in the XPath expressions just need to be multiplied by a fixed factor. Construct the XPaths using the loop index, like `post.xpath('./b[' + (3 * i + 1) + ']/text()')` and so on. `3 * i + 1` would be `1` in the first iteration (counting i from 0). It would be `4` in the second, etc.

Comment: This is just one of the possibilities. Alternatively you could loop over `//div[@id="mainDiv"]/div[@class="post"]/b` and use these inside the loop: `./text()`, `./following-sibling::br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]`, `./following-sibling::br[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]` to extract the text after the next `<br>` and the one after.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, that's a helpful push in a very promising direction.